# Change neo4j database location within python

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

I understand that I can set the database location by changing the following line in `/conf/neo4j-server.properties`

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
```

Is it possible to do this within a python instance? For example, I'm using [`neo4jrestclient`](http://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/info.html)

```
neo4j_login = {
    "username" : "neo4j",
    "password" : "supersecret",
    "url" : "http://localhost:7474"
}

from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
gdb = GraphDatabase(**neo4j_login)
```

Can I somehow set the location of the database I'd like to open to a local directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the REST client, then you're not talking to a local directory, so no - in any case you'll be using a local endpoint.   Via that REST client, I believe your only option is to point the server to a directory and then point the REST client to the same place you would have anyway.

Now, if this were java, you could use the neo4j-shell or other tools to open up any directory on your disk as a neo4j database; I don't believe that's an option with present python implementations but if I'm wrong about that someone else please jump in and indicate so.

Comment: Thanks. After posting the question I was poking around and found something called embedded neo4j. I _think_ this is what I'm looking for but the python modules don't seem to support it well. Can you say something about this?

Comment: Embedded neo4j is when you use the java API, and so the DB is embedded inside of your java application (as in, it's in the same memory space, same JVM).  From python, I suppose you could use jython so you're running python on top of the JVM, then embedded neo4j would be an option.